# How to temporarily disable input?

Tags: c#, unity

I have made a jump script and I want all input to be ignored when you are in mid air (so that way you don't have infinate jumps). How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to disable input, it's to check to see if the user can jump.
If you disable input: A. The players not going to be able to do anything. They won't be able to guide the character. They wont be able to grab ledges. Nothing. B. You'll still need to check to see when the user can jump because you'll need to know when to enable input again.

As a basic concept:

```
if (!isInAir) // if you are not in the air
{
    // do jump
}
```

If we were to implement this as a generic test:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool IsInAir;

    void Start()
    {
        IsInAir = true;
    }

    void OnFixedUpdate()
    {
        bool attemptJump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

        if (!IsInAir && attemptJump) // if we are not in the air, and we are attempting to jump
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        // other movement stuff

        IsInAir = true; // This will be set back to false if we are contacting an object.
    }

    void OnCollisionStay(Collision other)
    {
        // we are contacting an object. We can jump off this object.
        IsInAir = false;

        /* Todo: Limit jumping posibilities by checking contact normal and object information
            contained in 'other'. */
    }
};
```

The above sample has not been tested, and should consider you as able to jump whenever you are contacting a game object.